# Single IP, Multiple SSL Certs, NOT using wildcard, TLS on IIS 7 possible?

Tags: ssl, iis-7, iis-7.5

We host many sites with domains on a single IP ie. www.domain1.com, www.domain2.com. We want to secure /admin using SSL. Historically each SSL cert needs a unique IP address. These are small sites and acquiring / assigning an individual IP to each site is unrealistic both in terms of maintainability and cost. Because we are not using sub domains the wildcard SSL cert approach won't work.

Googling around I found that Apache can do this by using TLS, see answer here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/109766/ssl-site-not-using-the-correct-ip-in-apache-and-ubuntu

My question is whether this is possible with IIS 7.5 too? If so, does anyone know how to set this up?

Thanks in advance

Dave

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 2):

SSL and TLS basically are the same. TLS is the successor to SSL where TLS 1.0 is basically the same as SSL 3.1.

What makes the difference though is the support for [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). This allows the browser to tell the server for which hostname the request is without the need for the server to decrypt the  request.

Normally a webserver looks at the hostname header to decide for which virtual site the request is. But when SSL/TLS is used, the entire request (including all headers) are encrypted. In order to read the headers the server would have to decrypt the request but it can't do that without using the proper certificates. To know which certificate to use, it would need to know for which site the request is but it can't know that because that information is in the encrypted request. A classic chicken/egg problem. This is where SNI steps in.

SNI requires a reasonably new OS / browser / server and is not yet supported by IIS. It will be supported in Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8.0 (due for release this year).